# What is the best way of making concurrent animations?

Tags: algorithm, animation

this is an algorithm/data structure question about making different animations at the same time. For example, a ball is falling down one pixel in a millisecond, a bullet is moving 5 pixels in a ms, and a man is moving 1 pixel in 20 milliseconds. And think that there are hundreds of them together. What is the best way of putting all animations together, moving what we need to move in one function call, and removing the ones whose animation is completed? I don't want to create a thread for each one. What I want to do is to create one thread moving all items and sleeping until an object needs to be moved.

Note: I'm using Java/Swing, printing objects and images in JPanel.

Comment: That entirely depends on the platform. For example, using a transformation matrix based object animation will allow you to combine some animations into a single one (translation + scaling, etc).

Comment: All I do is using paint method and painting different objects and images different places in Java, Swing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently did something similar in Python. I don't know if this is the best method, but here's what I did.

Create an abstract `Event` class with the following public interface:

- `tick` - calculates how much time has passed since the last tick. Perform work proportional to that time span. This should be called frequently to create the illusion of smooth movement; maybe sixteen times a second or so.
- `isDone` - returns true when the Event has finished occuring.

Make a subclass of Event for anything that takes more than one frame to finish. Rotating, scaling, color changing, etc. You might create a `TweenEvent` subclass of Event if you want to move an image from one part of the screen to another. During each `tick`, redraw the image in a position farther away from the original position, and farther towards the destination position.

You can run many Events concurrently, like so:

```
Array<Event> events = new Array<Event>();

//add a bunch of TweenEvents here - one for a bullet, one for a ball, etc.

while(True){
    Sleep(1/16);
    for(Event e in events){
        e.tick();
        if (e.isDone()){events.remove(e);}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'm using a similar method and I find it a little bit complex. Maybe we can find a better way here :)